# jquery-ui tabs not working - js and css are included, but page is plain

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've used jquery-ui before and even used the Tabs aspect of jquery-ui before... but for some reason, it's not working today. What the heck am I doing wrong?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" />

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#tabs').tabs();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href='#tabs-1'>Email</a></li>
                <li><a href='#tabs-2'>Email 2</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div id='tabs-1'>
                <p>test</p>
            </div>
            <div id='tabs-2'>
                <p>test2</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

The page is just completely plain:

[image]

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that. And a jsFiddle of your code works fine. Are you getting any errors? Sure the scripts and CSS are loading?

Comment: As per previous commenter, I suspect the resources are not being found.

Comment: It is working for me http://jsfiddle.net/efortis/Wqq2F/, where are you testing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"

Comment: *facepalm* Thank you, I totally wasn't even checking the "src" vs "href" attribute.